# module not found in node_modules (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

when I execute:
 `yarn serve`
in my vuejs project terminal
I have this error:

````
* ./axios-api in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/dashboard/pages/UserProfile.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&```
````

Comment: Have you installed all the packages?

Comment: have you tried delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` then do `yarn install`? make sure to backup `yarn.lock` first

Comment: @AdamMudianto I just did, same error showing up

Comment: It looks like on the User Profile page you're importing ./axios-api but Webpack doesn't know about it. Maybe it's a typo in the path to axios/api?